# Prove that this group of matrices has order $p^3$

Tags: group-theory, matrices, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of upper triangular matrices $\in \mathcal{M}_3 (\mathbb{Z}_p)$ with ones on the diagonal. I've already proved that this group isn't abelian, but I don't know how to show that its order is $p^3$.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that we can choose only 3 entries.

Could you help me prove that?

How, in general, can I prove that the order of a given group is equal x?

(It is 58.22 in Kostrikin's Exercises in Algebra)

Comment: You're right. You can have $p$ entries in any of the $3$ spots.

Comment: But how does that make the group's order equal $p^3$?

Comment: It's the [rule of product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) from combinatorics.

Comment: @bilbo It's easy to see that there are at *most* $p^3$ elements in the group, because you can enumerate all of the upper triangular matrices.  What you need to show is that every one of those matrices corresponds to a _unique_ group element (i.e., that all those elements form a group).

Comment: I don't understand your "in general" question, by the way. Do you mean if you don't know the field for the elements in the matrices?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot that we wanted to show that the group's order is $p^3$, not a matrix's. As to the "in general" question I meant exactly that. But I see it's trivial now. We always count how many different matrices we can create with elements of a given field, don't we?

Comment: I would like to add that this group is well-known under the name *Heisenberg group modulo* $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each upper triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal looks like
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & a & b\\0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$$
for some $a$, $b$, and $c$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. There are $p$ possibilities for each of these entries, and so there are a total of $p^3$ upper triangular matrices with ones on the diagonal. But you've already shown that these matrices form the group $G$, and so $|G| =p^3$.

There are many different methods to determine the order of a group. The most straightforward is the method here, which is counting elements.

Comment: To be fair, as of the time of the question it might *not* have been the case that OP had proven they form a group $G$; it's very easy to show that multiplication of elements isn't abelian without actually showing that the elements form a group.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Maybe, but if so the OP should have worded the title and the question differently, since everything there indicates we know it's a group.